# Can I close InputStream right after creating InputSource?

Tags: java, xpath, inputstream

I have an `InputStream` that I'm converting to `InputSource` to run a few Xpath queries.

Can I close the `InputStream` right after creating the `InputSource` or only when I don't need the `InputSource` anymore?

This is my code:

```
InputStream stream = multipartfile.getInputStream()
InputSource source =  new InputSource(stream)
stream.close() //here
Node root = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
stream.close() //Or here?
```

Comment: `stream` is the data source for `source`, so of course `source` need it open to be able to read from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not close the `InputStream` before the parser did the work, otherwise it cannot read it. But if you have a look at the JavaDoc of `InputSource`, it shouldn't even be necessary to close the stream explicitly, as the parser should close it:

> An InputSource object belongs to the application: the SAX parser shall never modify it in any way (it may modify a copy if necessary). However, standard processing of both byte and character streams is to close them on as part of end-of-parse cleanup, so applications should not attempt to re-use such streams after they have been handed to a parser.

But if you want to make sure it is closed, you should do it after the parser did its work. Actually you should then do it in a `finally` block to be sure it is done even if exceptions occur, or you simply use a try-with-resources block that will auto-close it appropriately like:

```
try (InputStream stream = multipartfile.getInputStream()) {
    InputSource source =  new InputSource(stream)
    Node root = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Decorator pattern`. Short answer is **no**, you should not close the `InputStream` before using the source object, as it is being used in the functionality of `InputSource`.

If we look at an example of decorator pattern we can see why we should not alter the object passed as constructor parameter:

```
abstract class WindowDecorator implements Window {
    protected Window windowToBeDecorated; // the Window being decorated

    public WindowDecorator (Window windowToBeDecorated) {
         this.windowToBeDecorated = windowToBeDecorated;
    }
    public void draw() {
         windowToBeDecorated.draw(); //Delegation
    }
     public String getDescription() {
         return windowToBeDecorated.getDescription(); //Delegation
    }
}
```

You can see in this example that `windowToBeDecorated` as an object is being used in the `draw()` or `getDescription()` methods.

You can check more about Decorator pattern [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Java). Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-with-resources Statement, this ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.
here you can find a good example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html